# Probability chosing -defective -series

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

even I have understand probabilities how it works I find it difficult to achieve to solve 10 exercises in 10 right.I am doing mistakes. I want to calculate those with a calculator online or with some other technique that it need it makes it easier to solve.I will write 3 different examples of exercises. I want to have an easy solution **"same" way** in all **OR** I want to use a **calculator/software** for all or for each one case . Is any calculator that can solve those exercises?that would be perfect I wouldn't do mistakes and I will be sure for the result.

**Exercise 1(Boxes)**:I have a box 5 black balls,6 white balls.I pick 3 (I can't the balls back).

```
a)Find what is the possibility to be the third ball black
b)the last two balls white
```

**Exercise 2(defective)** :I have two companies A and B with packages. We take 30% of A and 70% of B.The 5% from A is defective (packages).

```
a)If we take 1 package what is  the probability to be defective?
```

**Exercise 3:(with serie )** : 4 white,5 black,7 red.We chose 4. What is the probability to come with the right way?

```
a)W B B R W
b)B B W B R
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork what you mean?Example ,for the first exercise I have already solve it with tree datagram..but I don't want to solve it with tree datatagram

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Is  any way to solve those exercises with calculators instead of hand by hand?

Comment: Hints for Exercise 1: "Find what is the possibility to be the third ball black" ::: Would the answer be different if you are being asked about the **first** ball black?

:::"the last two balls white"::: Would the answer be different if you are being asked about the **first** two balls white?

Comment: @user2661923 why? ofcourse it plays role

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the OP's reaction to my comment.

> Find what is the possibility to be the third ball black

Thought experiment:

Instead of having the balls drawn, a *moderator* writes down the numbers 1 thru 11, each on a separate slip of paper, and then **randomly** assigns each slip of paper to one of the balls.  This **random assignment** will then represent the order that the balls are drawn in.

Therefore, the probability of the 3rd ball being black is equivalent to the probability that the piece of paper with the number 3 on it was assigned to a black ball.  **Why** would such an occurrence be more or less likely than the probability that the piece of paper with the number 1 on it was assigned to a black ball?

**Answer**: the probability of the two occurrences is the same.  That is, assigning (at random) one piece of paper to one of the black balls is just as likely (no more and no less) than assigning a different piece of paper to one of the black balls.